# Google Play stopped working error

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I developed and published an App to Google Play and it was working fine until yesterday. App works as it should but when the users want to open the Achievements and Leaderboard in Google Play they get an error: "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped"

I know that the App is able to login into GP because I created some messages that update after login

```
public void onSignInSucceeded()
{
if(getApiClient().isConnected())
{
  loading.setText("Please wait while we load\n the Achievements panel, thank you...");
  ...
}
....
}
```

but the App cannot display the Achievements/Leaderboard anymore as it ones did.

I am not sure if anything changed with Google Play or Play Games but it just stopped working. Did't make any changes in the code nor uploaded a new package to Google Dashboard. It just simply stopped working... any thoughts?

thank you,

Dan

Update: the Stack trace error message is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "" at java.lang.long.invalidLong(Long.java:124) at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345) at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.client.a.a(SourceFile:498) at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.client.a.b(SourceFile:344) at com.google.android.gms.commom.internal.z.a(SourceFile:188)
```

Comment: Have you seen the reports of CRASH in Google Developer Console to have more info about the issue?

Comment: Yes I did. There are no CRASH reports at all. The app works but not Google Services so I am assuming that the crash report submissions go to Google Play Services, no?

Comment: Nop, if the client makes a report, the info must be into the Google Developer Console reports of crash; the Google play services app is running in your device?

Comment: I tried it on my phone and sent a report when Google Play crashed yesterday. I don't see any CRASH reports in my Dev Console

Comment: you can see the Exception when your app crashes, go to Report -> Preview -> Stack trace, copy the text and post in your question!.

Comment: It does not let me copy it but here it is: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "" at java.lang.long.invalidLong(Long.java:124) at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345) at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.client.a.a(SourceFile:498) at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.client.a.b(SourceFile:344) at com.google.android.gms.commom.internal.z.a(SourceFile:188)

Comment: Well thats the exception, you are tryin to parse a "" as long, is that value that now is "" the google play services version?

Comment: I am not sure because it is all part of the GP package. I am not sure what the  "" is. I am not passing any Long vars from my App just the ones in the BaseGameUtils. I did not make any changes to the App and it was working perfectly until Google did the GS update and now the App does not work in any of the devices I have nor the people that downloaded the App. I am not sure why it worked before and all of the sudden it broke...

Comment: do you have a google play services version defined into the library res/values/version.xml , something like  =>  <integer name="google_play_services_version">6111000</integer>

Comment: Yes this is under google-play-services_lib>res>values>version.xml. as usual. I am not sure what the Long var it is parsing will be

Comment: Could it be that you are somehow passing an invalid `requestCode` value for [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)?

Comment: free3dom: I have not made any changes at all to the code and it was working perfectly before. I am passing the same value in startActivityForResult as I did before

Comment: I am not sure if this is an issue with Apps that use the BaseGameUtils library only. I downloaded another App that does the same thing that mine did until it crashed. I am not sure if they used something else other than the BaseGameUtils libs. Is there another package or way to do the Achievements and Leaderboard besides using this BaseGameUtils libs?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services has just been updated! This fixed the error for us. So hopefully this will work for everyone else :)

Just download the latest version and it should work.

Comment: Is this a new version for the Android SDK Manager or for the device itself? i see no update on the Google play Services extra in te SDK Manager...

Comment: Just on your device. This is Google's mistake, so you shouldn't need to do anything development vise. My version is 2.1.17 on my device

Comment: It works now... I knew it wasn't me... thank you all for the comments and help....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for creating this as an answer, but apparently I can't comment as a new user. And we have no clue how to solve this error.

We have had the same error since yesterday. Everything worked perfectly before that, and players can still acquire achievements, but showing the Achievements UI crashes the game with a message: Google Play-services has crashed.

We tried downloading our 1.0 version from Play Store, and the same thing happened in that version. In other words: This can't be something we changed in our code. We have tried practically everything we can think of.

the API call that seems to trigger this is:

```
AndroidNativeBridge.GetInstance().startActivityForResult(
            Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mHelper
                    .getGoogleApiClient()), ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUEST);
```

Sorry again for posting as an answer, but this is the first related error we have found online.

Comment: I have the same issue for both startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent... and for startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent... nothing changed in the code. not even the test version works anymore. I know that we can connect to Google Play but when the app crashes when it tries to display either the Achievements or the Leaderboard